# Get and Filter Outlook events by Category using MS Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

am trying to filter Outlook events by category but am having trouble with the queries. I tried using the following queries but they return error messages.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=startswith(Categories, 'test')

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=contains(Categories, 'test')
```

I get the following output

```
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "The argument for an invocation of a function with name 'contains' is not a single value. All arguments for this function must be single values.",
```

What's the proper syntax for this query? Does the graph even support filtering by Category for events? If so, is there any other way in which I can filter events by category?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please use the following syntax:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category')

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get Uncategorised emails, any ideas? 
Also, what does a:a do?

Comment: I don't think `a:a` is an operator. I think `a:` is a variable declaration like "Let `a` be the letter I'm going to use as the unknown in the expression that I'm about to write after the colon". Then the actual filter expression is `a eq 'Red Category`. So it could also be `c:c+eq+'Red Category'`. Or **even** `b`.

Comment: @user8608110 you can get uncategorized emails by using the following filter : `not categories/any()`